# Build MonoDevelop + MonoMac on OS X

Tags: monodevelop, monomac

I'm following the instructions from here to build MonoDevelop on Mac OS X: [Building MonoDevelop on OS X](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Mac_Support/Building_MonoDevelop_on_OS_X)

I can build MonoDevelop just fine. I'd like to also build the MonoMac add in and use it.

The document says:

> "To include addins from extras, manually copy their build directories
>   into the MonoDevelop.app directory, e.g.
>
> cp -r ../../../extras/MonoDevelop.AspNet.Mvc/build/*
>   MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.AspNet.Mvc/"

However, I have no build directory under /extras/MonoDevelop.MonoMac.

I tried to follow this step to build extras:

> "To include additional addins from extras in the build, instead of
>   using the Mac profile, use configure --select to select addins. This
>   will write the default profile. Next, replace the line in
>   profiles/default that begins with "main"  with the one from
>   profiles/mac, then run configure again using the default profile."

But it does not give me the option to build the MonoMac extra.

Next, I try to compile the monodevelop.mdw. Again, I can build the main solution (MonoDevelop), but the extras fails with over 1000 errors.

Finally, I tried to take my existing monomac and macdev plugins and copy them into my master monodevelop.app bundle. But this breaks add solution/project dialog whenever I try to select a MonoMac project - it fails to load the Monodevelop.ide DLL.

Any advice on where I am going wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to make this work following the directions on the MonoDevelop site. Even manually adding the extras/MonoDevelop.MonoMac extra to the profile did not work.

In the end, I build MonoDevelop from source, using the mac profile.

Then I got the latest MonoMac pieces, and build them from source. I used

> make update

to install into my *installed* copy of MonoDevelop.

Then, I manually copied the following packages from my installed MonoDevelop to my newly compiled version from master:

- MacPlatform.dll
- MonoDevelop.iPhone
- MonoDevelop.MacDev
- MonoDevelop.MonoMac
- Xamarin.Ide

Any everything now works :)